# Translate project to my editorconfig

Tags: javascript, git, editor

`DISCLAIMER: Please, do not start "singlequotes masterrace", "tabs are over spaces"-related shitstorms. Thanks :)`

I wonder how to make this possible:

1. Project is using 4 spaces and doublequotes
2. I am using 2 spaces and singlequotes
3. Import project
4. Every opened file translate to 2 spaces and singlequotes
5. Save project as 4-spaces and doublequotes based
6. Commit it as 4-spaces and doublequotes files

I am web developer, JS ES6 (without flow), JSX (react), mainly using VS code.
This is not essental I '*can*' stick to the project rules. But this will save me much time.

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [Git smudge/clean filters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes). A pre-requisite is that you have a tool that does the conversion of 4 spaces and double quotes to 2 spaces and single quotes and vice versa. Assuming you have these two, let's call them 4to2converter and 2to4converter, do the following:

Edit (or create) your `.gitattributes` file by adding a line like this:

```
*.js filter=convert
```

This tells git that it should apply `convert` filter on all .js files. You can include other file types as well.

Then define what the convert filter does by adjusting git config:

```
$ git config filter.convert.smudge 2to4converter
$ git config filter.convert.clean 4to2converter
```

What happens now is that every time you commit .js files, the file is first ran through 2to4converter, and every time you do a checkout, it is first ran through 4to2converter.

Finally, ensure first that you don't have any uncommitted work, and run:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- **
```

This forces a checkout on all files, applying your newly defined filter.

Comment: Smudge and clean are special references?